# Filter group for a specific date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with a user_id and a date

```
|user_id|date_2check|
---------------------
|   1   | 2020-02-01|
|   2   | 2020-01-05|
```

And then a table with historical data

```
|row_id|user_id|everyday_checkin|
---------------------------------
|   1   |   1   |   2020-01-01   |
|   2   |   1   |   2020-01-04   |
|   3   |   1   |   2020-01-08   |
|   4   |   1   |   2020-01-12   |
|   5   |   1   |   2020-02-01   |
|   6   |   1   |   2020-06-01   |
|   7   |   2   |   2020-12-31   |
```

I would like to filter out all the rows from the historical table that are bigger than the first table, so it looks like:

```
|row_id|user_id|everyday_checkin|
---------------------------------
|   1   |   1   |   2020-01-01   |
|   2   |   1   |   2020-01-04   |
|   3   |   1   |   2020-01-08   |
|   4   |   1   |   2020-01-12   |
|   5   |   1   |   2020-02-01   |
```

Note that the row_id 6 is removed because the date is older than the first table and user_id 2 disappears because he has no entry lower than his date in table 2.

Thanks

Comment: you could use join on 2 criteria - id and date

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for possible compare `date`s from another `DataFrame` and compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal:

```
print (df2['user_id'].map(df1.set_index('user_id')['date_2check']))
0   2020-02-01
1   2020-02-01
2   2020-02-01
3   2020-02-01
4   2020-02-01
5   2020-02-01
6   2020-01-05
Name: user_id, dtype: datetime64[ns]

m = df2['user_id'].map(df1.set_index('user_id')['date_2check']).ge(df2['everyday_checkin'])
df = df2[m]

print (df)
   row_id  user_id everyday_checkin
0       1        1       2020-01-01
1       2        1       2020-01-04
2       3        1       2020-01-08
3       4        1       2020-01-12
4       5        1       2020-02-01
```